# If I have a while(1) loop in main, do i need a return value?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

In short, I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, programming in C++. My main method has a `while(1)` repeating a bit of code, and never leaves the loop.

Microsoft Visual Studio is allowing me to compile without a return value for the main method, even though it's declared `int main(int argc, char** argv)`. Is this standard for other compilers, or just a "feature" of Microsoft Visual Studio?

I realize I never get to the code that returns a value, but should I just thrown on a return 0; at the end anyway?

Comment: If you put in a `return 0` and compile with optimizations and maximum warnings, it'll complain about unreachable code.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 will actually accept things like `double *****main(){
}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the standard, the `main` function in C++ implicitly returns 0, even if there is no return statement in it.

---

The exact reference (from n3797): 3.6.1.5

> A return statement in `main` has the effect of leaving the main function (destroying any objects with automatic
>   storage duration) and calling `std::exit` with the return value as the argument. If control reaches the end
>   of main without encountering a `return` statement, the effect is that of executing
>
> `return 0;`

Answer (score 0):

The `return 0;` statement can be omitted from `main` even though its return type is `int`. It is defined by C++ standard. In this case it returns `0` by default.

Comment: wasn't it rather "even though" and not "even if"?